# Restart firewall from bash file

Tags: bash, debian, shell-script, services

I need to restart firewall periodically, so I created a bash file to add it to CRON tables.

In terminal, I restart firewall using command:

```
service firewall restart
```

but if I have similar line in my bash file (`myscript.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
service firewall restart
```

and run it from terminal (as root)

```
sh myscript.sh
```

the firewall is not being restarted.

What's the difference? How can I restart service from a bash file?

**EDIT**

I also tried this commands:

```
/etc/init.d/firewall stop
/etc/init.d/firewall start
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/firewall restart
```

And also tried to execute the file like that:

```
/bin/sh myscript.sh
```

Still not working.

**EDIT**
My bash script is looking like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ some statement ]; then
    /etc/init.d/firewall restart # also tried: eval /etc/init.d/firewall restart
    stat /some/file -c %Y > /root/statfile
    # if I add any statement here it is being executed, so it is not the fault of incorrect if statement
fi
```

Comment: What happens if you run the script using `set -x`?

Comment: Nothing - still the same effect

Comment: It would be interesting to see the `set -x` output, as it appears you're doing the right things.

Comment: Well... there is no output. Just the information, that the script was being invoked

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you need to restart the firewall periodically. Maybe you have an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and the problem with the service restart is connected. How do you know if the firewall restart was successfully or not?

Answer (score 3):

The environment of `cron` is not the same as the environment of your random login shell. Most likely something in your environment is not what your firewall script needs it to be.

Try checking `/var/mail`, or whatever your mail spool is. Cron defaults to mailing the output to the user whose crontab it executes something from, but if you haven't configured your MTA you won't see that output. If the output you find there is not enlightening, try adding `set -x` to the top of your script, and/or add the `env` command (without arguments) and compare the output to the output of the same command when run from your shell.

If all that fails, post the output and the *full* script (don't edit it -- just because you think it's all fine doesn't mean it is, and you can't expect help if you withold information).

Answer (score 1):

What if you do `/etc/init.d/firewall restart` instead of `service firewall restart`?

It may be the path.

Remember to make it executable:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

What are you intending with `some statement`

Extract

```
if [ some statement ]; then ...
```

That doesn't make sense

Comment: what do you mean? It's just an example, I'm using some real, working statement tested inside `if`

Comment: @Gacek the only part that we can't see is this `some statement`. If that test fails the firewall won't be restarted. This is what you're seeing, so it's possible that your `some statement` is failing.

Comment: And I'm telling you the `if` is working - as I wrote in my question, I tested it (added some debug code inside the `if` to test if it is fired.

Comment: It would really help, if you could update your question with the output of `sh -x myscript.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Sensible troubleshooting procedure would be to simplify your script such that it unconditionally restarts firewall. Add that script to cron and determine if a simple, unconditional restart is working as expected.

Assuming that works, add in your condition (the i [ mystery statement ] part) and try again.

Without knowing what condition you are testing for, it's difficult for anyone to tell you why it is not working from cron, but I would bet that the problem lies within that if statement, and some assumption you are making about your env that does not hold true for cron's env.

Comment: +1 I totally agree that this should be pretty easy to troubleshoot. Nice suggestion to start with an unconditional restart.

Answer (score 0):

The script must be invoked using sudo. Or by having another user in the the wheel administrator group account along with sudo. It all depends on what distro you are using with what options you can use and how to use them to run the script with high enough permissions.

```
sudo -u [username] -S myscript.sh < password_file.txt
```

When using a group account for file permissions, you must include it in the group permissions of the script file (myscript.sh) and be in a directory the the group has permissions to access. The user that is in the wheel or other group must be invoked with the script using the -u [usename] option. When using the wheel account I would not use the cron account as a user. You will also need to add the user to the sudo list. The wheel group has been deprecated in some distros as it has been proven to be a security risk. In that case, create an group for admin purposes and use that group for file permissions.

Instructions to add a user to the sudo list can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos ... Use this tutorial as a guide.

Also, if you include stderr code and/or redirect sdtout to a text file in your script it will give you an idea of any problems when invoking the script.

There are a vast number of ways and techniques regarding sudo and using it securely. It really is all about conventions and security policies of the user and/or company.

Comment: Script is being run as root user. Even as root the firewall is not being restarted when I invoke the script.

Answer (score 0):

When you expect script to run from CRON, you need to define PATH to include location of service binary (usually located under /sbin) (or) give absolute path like `/sbin/service firewall restart`

Also, can you share the output of below commands from your terminal session:

```
# which service
# bash -x <your-script-to-restart-fw>
# strace -e process -f bash -x <your-script-to-restart-fw>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script you need to change the first line, the so called shebang, to 
`#!/bin/bash`
 and then you invoke the script like this:
`bash myscript.sh`
Bash is a superset of sh and is capable of the same actions and even more actions as sh.
In cronjobs you should always use the bash command instead of the sh command.